# Weird wireshark record on netcut activity

Tags: arp, man-in-the-middle

As the title suggests, I have been running a wireshark session on machine A
while machine B was using some ARP spoofing software to disrupt the internet
connection of machine A. I expected to see that Machine B regularly sends packets with hijacked source IP addresses to everybody else on the LAN. But what I saw was that Machine B makes ARP requests about LAN members at (far too) regular intervals, and also requests about addresses - that seem random - not belonging to the LAN.
I would like to know why I saw that instead of what I expected.
A good answer could help devise a good way around ARP spoofing, and more importantly, help me understand what is going on here.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You know that wireshark has its own specialized Forum ?

Comment: Unless I am really confused about this, the weirdness of it is to blame on the ARP hijacking method, not on wireshark.

Comment: Even if: you find network specialists at this forum which know arp tricks too. And SO is about programming, not Arp or wireshark

Answer (score 0):

I did a bit more searching on the question, here's the explanation.

Firstly the fact that the victim machine doesn't receive forged arp packets is normal, since netcut - instead of corrupting the arp table of the victim - corrupts the gateway's arp table.

Of course, the flaw here is that the victim can in theory still utilize internet bandwidth, just for the sake of annoying the netcut user, who most of the time seeks to monopolize bandwidth.

As for the arp queries about random addresses, they apparently originate from a process other than Netcut.